# How to send a json from Flex to Rails through URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is it possible to send a JSON object through an URL?

I made scaffold in a rails test app where the controller receives a JSON object. In another hand, I have a GUI build it in Flex. How should I send the JSON from my flex app?

When I try to access through this url:

> `http://localhost:3000/test`

the rails app inserts an empty object but when I add a parameter Flex show me the following message: InvocationTargetException:The URL is not valid.

How I can send it without another library like RubyAMF....? Is it possible to send it just using flex > json > rails ?

Comment: what's your current AS3 code? (edit your answer to show it so we can give you more appropriate advice)  You can use the URLLoader object in AS3 to send JSON data to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it with:

```
req = new URLRequest("http://localhost:3000/tests/"+market_id);
    jrwloader  = new URLLoader();
    params = new URLVariables();
    req.data = strXml.toString();                               
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;                                                         
    req.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", URLRequestMethod.PUT));                                                          
    **req.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/xml'));**             jrwloader.load(req);
```

thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flex you should just create a HTTPService and post the JSON as a parameter using either POST or GET. That works for me. Showing your code might also help :-)